# Use Google Chrome to download software, but the software is in Chinese.

Tags: google-chrome, internet, download, language

I am using Google Chrome to download software installation files from an English website. But, when I installed them on my computer, they all appeared to be in Chinese (I am using a Chinese version of Windows 7). However, it was weird that the built-in web browser in one of those applications searches up English help contents. Could you please tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Would depend on the site, but some sites recognize the language the OS is in and therefore suggest the download with the language of your system. The sites themselves might be fully written in English, regardless of offering multilingual software.

In that case, those sites allow you to **choose** the specific download (so probe around the site for an English download). Also, it *would be* browser independent...

Comment: Something really weird is that, in the menus in one of the softwares, there are menu items in Chinese, and one or two in English. Is Windows tranlating these?

Comment: Probably not. The software might have been written in English first and then translated to Chinese. However, as it is the case for some open-source projects, the translators do it half-way and the default English names remain.